# how to make navigation drawer without listview

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer

Does anyone know how to replace a listview in navigationDrawer?
I don't know how do navigation drawer without I have to do listView.
I want to put imagenButtons and I would use setonclickListener for to go a fragment.
I would like to put look like

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- The main content view -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_route_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />




</LinearLayout>
```

I want use imageButton.setOnClickListener
But I don't know.
Samebody any idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
FrameLayout contentFragme = findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
content_frame.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1).setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then change the fragments in the `onClick()` based on their ids.
Here you go.

Comment: add 
    android:layout_gravity="start" to your LinearLayout, that way android will look for that space to set it as your drawer, and do as nikola says, but i think it should be the LinearLayour instead, FrameLayout will be the content of your view, you can also always call the buttons directly